# document template metadata sharepoint library

Tags: document-library, metadata

I have document template (Employee form) in a document library, when i update a template and publish then version get updated in document library for that document. But when i open that template again from library, version field exist in template does not update automatically. I have to manually update it. Is there any OOB feature to do it auto or any C# code i can get to do it. Can i do it using event receiver. Thanks